# Add List<String> to the JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I am trying to greate JSON  with the JSON library. At the momant I am creating JSONArray to add to add all the value in my List to it but I am facing this  Problem

> he method put(int, boolean) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String, List)

at this line `arrivalMoFr.put("mon-fri", timeEntries);` How can I add List to the `JSONArray`?

I appreciate any help.

**Code:**

```
    List<String> timeEntries = entry.getValue();

    try {
        JSONObject timeTable = new JSONObject();
        timeTable.put("route", route);

        JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
        info.put("direction", direction);

        JSONObject stops = new JSONObject();     
        stops.put("stops_name", key);

        JSONObject arrivals = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray arrivalMoFr  = new JSONArray();
                        //The error is here.
        arrivalMoFr.put("mon-fri", timeEntries);

        arrivals.put("mon-fri", arrivalMoFr);

        stops.put("arrival_time", arrivals);


        info.put("stops", stops);
        timeTable.put("info", info);

        System.out.println(timeTable.toString(3));


    }
```

**Edit:**
I added it like this but I am getting now this result:

```
JSONObject arrivals = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray arrivalMoFr  = new JSONArray();
                arrivalMoFr.put( timeEntries);

                arrivals.put("mon-fri", arrivalMoFr);
```

**Result:**

```
{
   "route": "4",
   "info": {
      "stops": {
         "arrival_time": {"mon-fri": [[
            "05:04",
            "18:41",
            "19:11",
            "19:41",
            "20:11"
         ]]},
         "stops_name": "Heiweg "
      },
      "direction": "Groß Grönau"
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't add `List` to JSON. You can create JSONArray from List but the thing you are asking is not possible.

Comment: You also try to use the method with wrong parameters. JSONArray's method 'put' expects an int and a boolean while you try to pass a String and a list to this method.

Comment: Please see my edit code question: why am I getting at the begening an the the emd of the JSONArray the ` [[` twice?

Answer (score 4):

```
JSONArray att = new JSONArray(YourList);
```

Comment: Please see my edit code question: why am I getting at the begening an the the emd of the JSONArray the ` [[` twice?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert `List<String>` to JSON

```
List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
listStrings.add("a");
listStrings.add("b");

Gson objGson = new Gson();
System.out.println(objGson.toJson(listStrings));
```

Output

```
["a","b"]
```

Comment: I prefer Gson when the JSOn is not multple Dimension. What is the Gson  equivalent code of my JSON code?