# Java query data type & how to transform?

Tags: java

I was a Python developer, but I got a Java project now.

I never code Java so I have some questions about the query syntax of Java.

First:

```
TypedQuery<String> query1= JPA.em().createQuery("Select distinct c.host from  table As c", String.class);

 List<String> results = query1.getResultList();
    JsonArray value =  new JsonArray();
    for (int j=0; j < results.size(); j++) {
         System.out.println(results.get(j));
        }
```

Another one:

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> query2 = JPA.em().createQuery("Select distinct c.version, c.year, c.month, c.rate, c.tcount from sw_fig1 As c ,object[].class);
```

1. About the `TypedQuery<>`  the type is depends on how many result in each 
   data?

   Like first query only select one column so it set String? Many columns use `object[]`?

   Or just the data type what I need?
2. I wanna sent the List which called **results** to front by JSON,so I new an JsonArray, and tried to add data of **results** in JSONArray.

   But it will error:

   ```
   add(com.google.gson.JsonElement) to JsonArray cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)
   ```

   I print the type of **results** it display:

   ```
   java.util.ArrayList.
   ```

   It made me confusion, cuz I thought JSONArray  can add array or string to be value right?

How can I fix it , and if anyone can let me know the concept, I will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Type is basically depends what u wrote in createQuery method
   https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-

you may want to look to java generics

2. As I can see from your error you are using Gson, so u

   ```
   List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
   listStrings.add("a");
   listStrings.add("b");

   Gson objGson = new Gson();
   System.out.println(objGson.toJson(listStrings));
   ```

[Add List<String> to the JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778770/add-liststring-to-the-jsonarray)

Comment: Thanks for you answer .
I saw the  page before , so I know it can convert by objGson.toJson().
But when I use loop to get each result and also the type display "java.lang.String".
I still can't  direct access them into Json?

Comment: could u provide code, didn't quite understand what u mean

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own objects that get automatically converted to JSON by implementing `Serializable` and add `@Produces(MediaType.JSON)` to your endpoint. These are Spring ([Serialize](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization) and [RequestMapping](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-new-requestmapping-shortcuts)) annotations, which takes care of those annoying transformations.

```
public class JSON implements Serializable {...}

@GetMapping("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.JSON)
public JSON getJson(){...}
```

Your query would then look like this

```
TypedQuery<JSON> query2 = JPA.em().createQuery("Select distinct c.version, c.year, c.month, c.rate, c.tcount from sw_fig1 As c ,JSON.class);
```